# Error importing msado15.dll

Tags: c++, database, dll, compiler-errors, ado

I'm trying to import msado15.dll into my c++ project but I get a bunch of errors like these:

```
 error C2018: unknown character '0x40' 
 error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'ÿÿ¸'
 error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

Here's my include directive:

```
#include "C:\program files\common files\system\ado\msado15.dll"
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `import` rather than `include`.

Answer (score 2):

you also need to rename EOF

```
#import "C:\program files\common files\system\ado\msado15.dll" rename("EOF", "EndOfFile")
```

Don't ask me why.